# Calculated column in mySQL based on another column after a calculation

Tags: mysql, function, view

Found a few similar links but can't apply it to my own work.

I'm working on a mySQL game rental database and I'm trying to get the column of late fees to calculate - I tried to create a function but couldn't get it quite right.

I have a game table (Game) which includes the overdue per day charge. I have a rental table (Rental) which has the due return date and the actual return date.

I want to create a function (or a view- whichever is more suitable) to calculate the overdue fee based off these dates.

For example

Game
Over_due_charge_per_day 3.00

Rental
Due_return_date 01-12-16
Actual_return_date Null
over_due_charge ?

When actual return date is > due_return_date I need to calculate the over_due_charge_per_day.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to join both tables and then use this logic:

Update Game 
set latefees=(Case when return_date > due_return_date then (return_date-due_return_date)*3 else 0 end)

Comment: select g.game_id, g.game_name, if(datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) > 0, datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) * g.overdue_charge_per_day, 0) as Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD 
from rental as r
left join game as g
on r.game_id = g.game_id
where month(r.return_date)=month(now())

Comment: I came up with this solution, thanks for the help though